# Swift UIBarButtonItem to unwind to the previous controller - not working

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I have two controllers with `ViewController` and `ClassMapViewController`. In the `ClassMapViewController`, I have a `UIBarButtonItem` which upon tapping would close `ClassMapViewController` and go back to the `ViewController`.

```
import UIKit     
class ViewController: UIViewController { 
    @IBAction func unwindToHome(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    }   
}

ClassMapViewController:UIViewController{
    var mapView:MapClass=MapClass()
    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mapView.latitude=43.679456
        mapView.longitude=-79.624712
        mapView.title="HelloWorld"
        mapView.address="firstmarker"
        mapView.zoom=12
        view=mapView.getView()
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=UIBarButtonItem(title:"Back",style:.plain,target:self,action:"previous")
    }

    func previous(){
        present(ViewController(),animated:true,completion:nil)
        dismiss(animated:true,completion:nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, I believe you are missing the **#selector** in your argument list.

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=UIBarButtonItem(
    title: "Back", 
    style: .plain,
    target: self, 
    action: #selector(previous)
)
```

You would need an **@objc** modifier on the function you are calling, but also, I don't think you can call ViewController like you do in your present() method below—you'd need to provide an actual reference to your VC.

```
@objc func previous() {
    present(ViewController(),animated:true,completion:nil)
    dismiss(animated:true,completion:nil)
}
```

Comment: the #selector and @objc seemed to work ok, but the present and dismiss doesn't do anything. It supposed to exit MapViewController and move to ViewController

Comment: You can't just call out 'ViewController' in your present() method call. It needs to be a reference to that ViewController.